# eBPF: retrieve `fd` of the pinned bpf program

Tags: filesystems, file-descriptor, bpf, ebpf

I know that `eBPF` program can be pinned to `/sys/fs/bpf` (default location of small `bpffs`. For example using `bpftool` :

```
$ bpftool prog load ./my_bpf.o /sys/fs/bpf/my_bpf
```

I was expecting that `open("/sys/fs/bpf/my_bpf")` would return me the value of file descriptor allocated for `my_bpf` by the kernel. But `open()` call just fails, I think it returns `-EINVAL`.

In this case, what is the purpose of pinning? How do I normally obtain `fd` of a BPF program, given that there might be lots of them currently loaded. I know that `libbpf` allows to retrieve `fd` from `id`, but what if I don't have an `id` either?

Comment: As you already guessed, `bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET, …)` (there is probably a wrapper in libbpf indeed) is the answer. You have other possibilities now that IDs exist, such as `bpf(BPF_PROG_GET_FD_BY_ID, …)` that needs the ID of the program (as shown with `bpftool prog show`)—and that's if you have an ID of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET, …)` wrapped in `bpf_obj_get()` in libbpf provided by kernel returns `fd` of the pinned object. Path to pinned object is an argument to `bpf_obj_get()`.